# Timed Out Exception ( Sending Data From Android To PHP Page )

Tags: android, http, exception, send

I am trying sending data from android application (with emulator) to web server (a php page) nowadays. Firstly, I had tried this program with emulator and it was working successfully. After that, I tried this program with telephone but an exception occurred :

--> IO Exception : The operation timed out.

One part of my code :

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.33:90/takeDatas.php");
try {                   
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("enlem", latitude ));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("boylam", longitude ));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    Toast.makeText(ReportLocationActivity.this, "Client protokol exception ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Toast.makeText(ReportLocationActivity.this, "IO exception "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I hope you will help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, I see only this exception.

Comment: Have you checked your webserver is correctly listening on port 90 on your machine?

Comment: Try visiting the PHP page in your phone browser, does it load? If your phone is not on the same network, it can't reach the host because it's using a private IP address.

Comment: @molnarm- Yes, my phone browser couldn't connect to my php page. What can I do?

Comment: @MisterSquonk - Yes, my webserver is correctly listening on port 90 on my pc. ( this program was working smoothly with emulator )

Comment: @iremce: Is the IP address of your machine REALLY 10.0.2.2 ??? You do know that that is just the IP address used by the emulator don't you? Also, whatever your machine's IP address is, have you opened port 90 on your firewall?

Comment: @MisterSquonk: Of course my machine ip address is not 10.0.2.2 . How can I open port 90 on my firewall?

Comment: @iremce: "Of course my machine ip address is not 10.0.2.2" - OK, so why are you using that in the code example you posted above? As for opening port 90 on your firewall - it depends on the firewall sw/hw you're using - check the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

10.0.2.2 is the IP that the emulator attributes to the host machine.

And in general, 10.x.x.x is part of a [private IP block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network).

So you must be hosting the server on the same machine the emulator is running on? Thats the only way I could see it working inside the emulator.

Anyway your app needs the actual IP of your server, and if you want it to work outside your network, you'll need your public IP (*find yours [here](http://showip.net/)*), and setup port forwarding for port 90 if you have a router. [This site](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/routerindex.htm) is horribly ad riddled, but has a massive collection of router specific instructions.

Comment: agreed @iremce is using local host rather than static IP. if you can't get a static IP use a dynamic IP service such as dyn-dns.com